# Optimize a multi-utility command to a single-utility command

Tags: optimization, awk, sed

I have a large file that has sections separated by `###` marks.  The output has a blank line, some random lines, another blank line, then the lines I want to do a word count on, followed by another blank line.  I can get the data I want but I'm using several pipes together and I think it can be done better with an awk or sed one liner.  Can you help?

Example of a file

```
...  
sdf  
asdf  
asdf  
asdf  


###################### Usage ###########

a  
asdf    

asdf    
asdf    
70  
80  
90  
100  

################



sfad

asdf  
asff  
...
```

The command I have that works is:

```
awk '/Usage/{flag=1; next}/####/{flag=0} flag' *|
  sed  -n '0,/^$/! p'|
    awk '/^$/{flag=1; next}/^$/{flag=0} flag'|
      wc -l
```

The first `awk` pulls that section of data in the file I want to work with.
The `sed` skips the first blank line.
The second `awk` pulls the data between the second blank line to the third blank line.
Then I get my word count.

Comment: @EdMorton: I believe the expected answer is `6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (you could turn it into a one-liner, if desired):

```
awk '
   FNR==1 { blankCount = inSection = count = 0 } # initialize vars. for every file
   /^#+ Usage #/ { inSection=1; next }           # section start, set flag
   inSection && /^#+/ { print count; nextfile }  # section end, print result, proceed to next file
   inSection {                            # a line inside the section of interest
     if (NF == 0)  { ++blankCount; next } # a blank line, count it and skip
     if (blankCount == 2) { count+=NF }   # a line after the 2nd blank one, count its words
   }
' file                                    # supports multiple input files
```

Note:

- The code assumes that there are at least 3 blank lines in each section and that the words / non-blank lines between the 2nd blank line and the 3rd one or the end of the section (whichever comes first) should be counted.
  With the sample input, the result is `6`.
- The code counts *words* (whitespace-separated fields, reflected in `NF`, the number of fields) rather than lines, but since your input only has one word per line, the line count (which is what your `wc -l` command does) is the same as the word count.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/Usage/ { inBlock=1 }
inBlock {
    if (NF) {
        if (numEmptyLines == 2) {
            numWords += NF
        }
    }
    else {
        if (++numEmptyLines == 3) {
           print numWords+0
           inBlock = numEmptyLines = numWords = 0
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
6
```

Comment: This works but I forgot to mention sometimes data will be missing so it will be blank line, data, blank line then ###.  Running this will return count 1 because it will call in the following ### and end on the blank line after.  Thank you Ed.